# Webview removes all whitespace before and after HTML entity

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview, webview

I have a NSString (with some HTML entities mixed in) being displayed in an UIWebview. Whenever an entity is displayed in the webview, the surrounding whitespace is stripped.

From source:

```
"I like Bill &#38; Ted's Excellent Adventure."
```

As displayed in webview:

```
"I like Bill&Ted's Excellent Adventure."
```

Comment: Are you using any special find/replace rules on special characters?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "special find/replace rules" though I'm not doing any find/replace within the app itself.

Comment: ONLY IF you can't find a setting in the iOS objects you are using, I know `&nbsp;` is displayed as " " (a space). You can do a replace on `"&#38;"` with `"&nbsp;&#38;&nbsp;"`. I would recommend this only if no other solution is found.

Comment: As @ToddBFisher suggests, a last ditch effort would be to override whatever find/replace is being done automatically.  Look into the docs for NSString and the other iOS objects that you're using until you find the cleaning function that strips/trims whitespace.

Comment: Thanks! Found the problem. it was "stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]" in function "parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser foundCharacters:(NSString*)string"

Answer (score 1):

when you show string on screen **first** you have to trim it. and then show.
There is a method of `NSString` **stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet** to trim in this we pass a character set. Two  class methods of this set is already in documentation but you can also create your own set as your requirement.Use `whitespaceCharacterSet` or `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` to remove whitespace around strings.

```
NSString *stringAfterRemovingWhiteSpace = [stringBeforeRemovingWhiteSpace stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```